# I want to extract the last substring "TEXT" but the INSTR syntax doesn't do in postgresql. Please help me

Tags: postgresql-9.2

```
Select text, 
       Instr(text,’.’,1,4) as pos_4dot,
       Length(text) as len_string,
       Substr(text,Instr(text,’.’,1,4) as pos_4dot)+1,length(text)-Instr(text,’.’,1,4) as pos_4dot))
From substr_instr;
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables. ([edit] your question - do **not** put code or additional information in comments)

Comment: Note that Postgres 9.2 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Comment: Sample data would help your question here.